# Copying from mount share drive to local folder through script

Tags: bash, mount, smb, rm

This is my first time trying to work with Linux Scripts so this may be something obvious.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Remove all contents from local folder - rm /home/user/Documents/Exercise/
2. Copy files from a shared windows network drive - cp smb://server/arc/Exercise%20Files/Word/

So from my understanding my command should look like this

```
  rm /home/user/Documents/Exercise/
  cp smb://server/arc/Exercise%20Files/Word/ /home/user/Documents/Exercise/
```

But anytime I try and run either of the above commands I get the following error:

```
  "rm: cannot remove `/home/user/Documents/Exercise/': Is a directory"
  "cp: cannot stat `smb://server/arc/Exercise%20Files/Word/': No such file or directory"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Kind Regards,

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your request and your test, let me point what is not written properly:

---

Remove all contents from local folder

```
rm /home/user/Documents/Exercise/
```

Error says *rm: cannot remove /home/user/Documents/Exercise/': Is a directory*

You should

```
  rm /home/user/Documents/Exercise/*
```

which will delete everything inside the directory, but not the directory.

---

Copy files from a shared windows network drive

```
  cp smb://server/arc/Exercise%20Files/Word/ /home/user/Documents/Exercise/
```

Error says *cp: cannot stat smb://server/arc/Exercise%20Files/Word/': No such file or directory*

You should check if route `smb://server/arc/Exercise%20Files/Word/` is correct. Then, use the following:

```
cp smb://server/arc/Exercise%20Files/Word/* /home/user/Documents/Exercise/
```

Comment: Thankyou for your assistance. I have adjusted the rm command and have that working successfully.

I still do not have the copy command though. The folder I am trying access does need password permission. Would that be causing the issue?

Comment: Could be. Try listing the directory to see if it works: `ls -l cp smb://server/arc/Exercise%20Files/Word/`. Then post the message / error you get!

Comment: `ls: cannot access smb://server/arc/Exercise%20Files/Word/: No such file or directory` 

This directory is 100% correct and I can access it through Nautilus

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a directory if it has content within it.
To delete the content and the directory at the same time, use the following command:

```
rm -r /home/user/Documents/Exercise/
```

This recursively deletes the directory and any content within it.

To copy the file, I believe you have to mount the directory beforehand, like so:

```
mount -t cifs //server/share /mnt/mount_directory -o user=username
```

Can you confirm if that works?

Comment: I have mounted the drive as such `/home/user/Documents/ExerciseShare/` so my revised coding looks like this: `cp /home/user/Documents/ExerciseShare/Exercise%20Files/Word/ /home/user/Documents/Exercise/` yet I am still receiving this error `cp: cannot stat /home/user/Documents/ExerciseShare/Exercise%20Files/Word/: No such file or directory
`

Answer (score 0):

Remove / Delete Command:
`rm -rfv /home/user/Documents/Exercise/*`

Copy Command:
`cp -rfv /home/user/Documents/ExerciseShare/ExerciseFiles/Word/ /home/user/Documents/Exercise/`